# Reloading Data in TableView after completing parse function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, reload

I am trying to reload the data after the function is completed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let presentingVC = presentingViewController as? DealsViewController {

 //checks if presenting VC's city is the same as original, doesn't run if it is      
 if presentingVC.city != self.currentCity {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //reloads the data but before completion of the below function "getDealInfo"
            presentingVC.DealsTableView.reloadData()
            presentingVC.DealsTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
//checks if presenting VC's city is the same as original, doesn't run if it is        
if presentingVC.city != self.currentCity {
        presentingVC.city = self.currentCity
        presentingVC.deleteAllDeals()
        //this is the function that gets called
        presentingVC.getDealInfo()
        presentingVC.cityOutlet.setTitle(self.currentCity,for: .normal)
        }
       
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    searching = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

As you can see, I call the reload function after returning to the previous view controller for new information that is supplied. However, the tableview updates prior to receiving the new values. As a result, my tableView is empty, however my values are stored in my arrays.

getDealInfo is Asynchronous:

```
    func getDealInfo() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Deal")
    query.whereKey("City", equalTo: city)
    query.order(byDescending: "Priority")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: 
    Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            self.dealsArray.append(object["Deal"] as! String)
              }
            }
       }
    })
 }
```

Comment: Are those synchronous methods or async? If they're synchronous just reorder your code. I don't know why you have the same if statement twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a completion handler to `getDealInfo` in order to be notified when it finishes:

```
func getDealInfo(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    //Do async work
    completionHandler()
}
```

Then in the calling code:

```
presentingVC.getDealInfo {
    self.presentingVC.DealsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

If the completion handler isn't being called in the main thread then you want to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` like you're currently doing so the call to `reloadData` is done in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Are those synchronous methods or async? If they're synchronous just reorder your code. I don't know why you have the same if statement twice. Just combine it into one and call reload data after you run your function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let presentingVC = presentingViewController as? DealsViewController {
//checks if presenting VC's city is the same as original, doesn't run if it is        
if presentingVC.city != self.currentCity {
        presentingVC.city = self.currentCity
        presentingVC.deleteAllDeals()
        //this is the function that gets called
        presentingVC.getDealInfo()
        presentingVC.cityOutlet.setTitle(self.currentCity,for: .normal)
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //reloads the data but before completion of the below function "getDealInfo"
            presentingVC.DealsTableView.reloadData()
            presentingVC.DealsTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        }
       
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    searching = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

If they're asynchronous then you'll need to look at providing some kind of completion block. But without knowing if   `presentingVC.getDealInfo()` is async or not it's hard to know what to suggest. I feel like we're missing some more vital code here

Comment: thanks for responding so soon. It is asynchronous. How would I show such a completion block?